# MySQL JOIN -- Complicated Select Statement

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables. One for users, one for posts, and a join table linking the two other tables.

Here's some sample data from the join table.

```
| id | user_id | post_id | timestamp |
|----|---------|---------|-----------|
| 1  |    1    |    1    | 4-17-2012 |
| 2  |    1    |    2    | 4-16-2012 |
| 4  |    2    |    2    | 4-17-2012 |
| 5  |    3    |    1    | 4-16-2012 |
|____|_________|_________|___________|
```

I want to write a SELECT query that will do the following:

1) Select all the posts for a user with a timestamp of 4-17-2012

AND

2) If there is no post entry in the join table for that user, select those posts as well.

So... 
For user_id = 1, post 1 would be selected, but not post 2, because post 2 is not 4-17-2012
For user_id = 2, both posts would be selected, post 1 because there is no entry for user_id = 2 and post_id = 1, and post 2 because it is 4-17-2012
For user_id = 3, post 1 would not be returned, but post 2 would be, because there is no entry for user_id = 3 and post_id = 2.

Here's an example of what I've been trying:

SELECT * FROM posts AS p
 LEFT JOIN posts_users as pu ON ( p.post_id = pu.post_id )
 WHERE ((pu.user_id = $user_id AND pu.timestamp = 4-17-2012) OR (pu.post_id IS NULL)

If there was a post_id = 3 row in posts, then it would have NULL for all posts_users columns, because of the LEFT JOIN, which helps satisfy #2. But if there's anyone at all with a posts_users entry for post_id = 3, then there will be no NULL. Is there a way in MySQL that we can have the logic for #2?

I'm doing this all in a framework that was already written out in PHP, and in a way that would make it very difficult for me to have to deal with using PHP to filter the returned results. Trust me on that one. Is there a way for me to use an SQL statement to accomplish this, or do I have to try and make a workaround in PHP after I get the results of some other query?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking into this further, it looks like I could use NOT EXISTS? I've never used this before, how would I use it in this context? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

select * from user left outer join posts_users on user.id = posts_users.user_id left outer join posts on posts.id = posts_users.post_id where timestamp = '4-17-2012' or timestamp = NULL

Comment: That exact statement doesn't work (it doesn't have the user_id, for example), but it lead me to the answer, so I'll give you the checkmark. The statement that I used is (basically) the following (these actually aren't the names of the tables or columns, I'm just simplifying them). It's awful. May God have mercy on my soul.

`SELECT posts.* FROM users LEFT JOIN posts on (1)
 LEFT JOIN posts_users ON ((posts.id = posts_users.post_id) AND (users.id = posts_users.user_id))
 WHERE (users.id = $user_id) AND ((posts_users.timestamp = '4-17-2012') OR (posts_users.timestamp IS NULL))`